# Calculating discount in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to calculate discount based on a person's age category and amount of visits at a hair salon. It's just not working properly though. It doesn't calculate the proper discount until the second click and then it does some weird stuff if I keep pressing calculate. Just wondering where I am going wrong, thanks.

```
' Discount
If radAdult.Checked = True Then
    discount = 0

ElseIf radChild.Checked = True Then
    discount = totalPrice * 0.1

ElseIf radStudent.Checked = True Then
    discount = totalPrice * 0.05

ElseIf radSenior.Checked = True Then
    discount = totalPrice * 0.15
End If

' Additional discount
If txtClientVisits.Text >= 1 And txtClientVisits.Text <= 3 Then
    additionalDiscount = 0

ElseIf txtClientVisits.Text >= 4 And txtClientVisits.Text <= 8 Then
    additionalDiscount = totalPrice * 0.05

ElseIf txtClientVisits.Text >= 9 And txtClientVisits.Text <= 13 Then
    additionalDiscount = totalPrice * 0.1

ElseIf txtClientVisits.Text >= 14 Then
    additionalDiscount = totalPrice * 0.15
End If

totalPrice = baseRate + serviceRate - (discount + additionalDiscount)
```

Comment: You didn't post all code. Can you post **where** it doesn't calculate properly?

Comment: Switch option strict on

Answer (score 0):

The type of the `txtClientVisits.Text` property is a String. The comparison operators `<`, `>`, `>=`, and `<=` for strings perform a lexicographic comparison. VB will then convert `14` to the string "14" and so compare each digit one-by-one, *which is not what you want*.

(This is why I don't like VB.NET - because it performs these implicit conversions without warning you).

You will need to explicitly convert the number in the textbox to an actual number, then compare based on that:

```
Dim clientVisits As Integer = CInt( txtClientVisits.Text )
If clientVisits >= 1 AndAlso clientVisits < 4 Then
    additionalDiscount = 0
ElseIf clientVisits >= 4 AndAlso clientVisits < 9 Then
    additionalDiscount = totalPrice * 0.05
ElseIf clientVisits >= 9 AndAlso clientVisits < 14 Then
    additionalDiscount = totalPrice * 0.1
ElseIf clientVisits >= 14 Then
    additionalDiscount = totalPrice * 0.15
End If
```

I note you used inclusive boundary values. That works for integer values but will fail for continuous (floating-point) values. Note how I'm using `>=` and `<` instead of `>=` and `<=` to avoid that case.

Also, note I'm using the `AndAlso` operator which is short-circuiting (compared to `And` which is not). This isn't a functional change, it just means the program will run slightly faster.

Also, you don't need to do `ElseIf radChild.Checked = True Then` because the value of the `.Checked` property is already a boolean value, you can do this instead:

```
ElseIf radChild.Checked Then
```

Comment: option strict is your friend

Comment: Doesn't seem to be making a difference @Dai

Comment: @YoungMogul what happens when you step-through debug it?

Comment: I don't get an error it just displays the wrong value for the total price

Comment: @YoungMogul I'm not asking you about errors. I'm asking you to step-through debug it with breakpoints and the Autos / Locals window.

Comment: {Text = "4"} is underlined in red for txtClientVisits and "4" is underlined in red for txtClientVisits.Text